# Running code from BSS section

Tags: c, assembly

In a buffer overflow attack, it's possible to run code from the BSS section (assuming the user disabled some security protections).  How is code running there different than code running in the text section?  Does it make sense to push things onto the stack while running code from the BSS section?  If not, how can functions be called from there?

I'm using linux x86.

Comment: "it's possible to run code from the BSS section" - is it? I'd be surprised if it were an executable segment by default. In what OS / environment?

Comment: If you can get it running, then it's no different from a code section. You can use the stack too.

Comment: Please be more specific, on which OS you're asking the question.

Comment: Without explicit OS limitation of execution, you can run code from anywhere (stack, heap, bss, data). You can read something about NX bit if you would like to know something about limiting the execution.

Comment: Well, there's also the issue of the bits set on the descriptors when you're in protected mode, @j123b567.  However, see my answer below for a way around that at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  Provided that the memory segment or selector that holds the BSS is not marked non-executable you can easily execute code from it if:

1. You know where it is in memory
2. You have a way to control the EIP to redirect execution here
3. You have some input (file, actual input, network or environment) that will end up in a statically allocated variable.

Simply inject your code into #3 and you're off to the races.

By the way..  I would not expect BSS to be marked executable, but don't despair.  This by no means indicates that some other selector doesn't point at exactly the same memory and is marked executable.  This means that you could approach it through BSS to inject code since that will be read/write and then through some other selector to execute.

For example, I find a fair number of examples where CS is pointing to precisely the same memory as DS, but CS is read-only and executable while DS is readwrite and non-executable.  Make sense?

Comment: Note that protection usually works through paging, so using a different selector doesn't help you one bit.

Comment: @jester I'm not suggesting that he can modify another process' memory but that the process into which he is injecting code may reference the same memory in more than one way.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The protections are set per page, not per segment at least in current operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

As much as i am aware, your premise of the BSS segment containing executable instructions is flawed. 
The **BSS segment** is used to **hold only static variables** that haven't been assigned values for example:

static char *test_var;

The **text segment is the segment** that contains the **executable instructions** and not the BSS segment.

For more clarity refer to:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment

Also, you might want to look at **Virtual Memory layout**. The link http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/ illustrates this very well with diagrams etc.

However, if you want to see **which segments** of an executable are marked as **executable**, use this tool called **readelf** on an executable as shown below:

readelf -l ./test